# Font Awesome issues showing error messages

Tags: html, css, webfonts, font-awesome-5

I downloaded font awesome  5 to use for free,but when I load it I get an error message showing:Also define the standard property 'filter' for compatibility css(vendorPrefix) and also a small looking shape at the place where the icons position is supposed to be.Attached is the error screenshot image from vscode.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand your question. but I try to suggest something for you.

Use latest version of font awesome.

Link Fontawesome via CDN and check you are still facing same issue or not?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Download fontawesome 6 free for web and follow the example code to use it :- [Download](https://fontawesome.com/download)

```
<head>
  <!-- our project just needs Font Awesome Solid + Brands -->
  <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
  <!-- uses solid style -->
  <i class="fa-brands fa-github-square"></i>
  <!-- uses brand style -->
```

Let me know, If your issue is solved.

Comment: Ok will try that when I get back home on my pc.Thanks a lot